# What state needs to be stored to allow resumable hash computations?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography

This question is only indirectly connected with a real-world problem, and is more out of interest. I have no real knowledge of how current real-world hash algorithms work internally.

I do know that typical hash computations (and CRC computations etc) work incrementally, updating some state <strike>for each byte/word in turn</strike> [it turns out that the algorithms work a block at a time, though the interfaces often handle that automatically]. So a partially complete hash computation can be resumed later - store that state, then reload it and continue where you left off. There are questions about this on SO already, but they seem to all to relate to particular libraries.

From ancient knowledge of CRC-16 (yes, really - due to obsolete file formats), I have the impression that the CRC value itself is all the state you need to store to resume the calculation. Obviously implementations can be written in strange ways, but in principle the CRC-16 of the content of the part of the file seen so far is complete state needed to resume the computation from that point.

Is that true of all the common hash computations used now? Particularly MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256. Or must some other (additional or alternative) state be stored in order to resume the computation?

Obviously the position to resume from in the file is needed, but in addition to that, what precise state do you need to store in order to resume a hash computation using common hash functions.

For extra bonus credit - how would I access that state using Crypto++ in C++? (a link or reference to the correct section of the documentation might be very helpful).

I'm tagging this as "algorithm" because that's the focus here - the requirements that arise from the real-world algorithms, not the implementations for any particular language or library.

Comment: @Mitch - you can perform the computation for e.g. the first half of a large file, then save the state of the computation. Then later, you can load that state and resume the computation, deriving the same hash for the whole file that you would have if you had done the job in one go. If you have very large files that can only be accessed via a slow and/or unreliable connection, that can be useful.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But how common is this? Files must be very large.

Comment: @Mitch - that's why this is mostly out of interest - I doubt I really need it, but I got curious. I'll be hashing the content of multiple several-terabyte USB2 hard drives, which will take days, but I only need to resume at the file level - not partial files.

Comment: The possible problem I foresee is that due to birthday paradox a relatively small hash of multi-terrabytes won't really be that useful.

Comment: @Mitch - it depends what you plan to use it for. This is as the (possibly first stab) at detecting and tracking duplicate files. Some of the files will be a few GB, but even so, the probability of being misled by hash collisions is fairly low - especially when also recording file sizes, so the hash is a tie-breaker for equal-size files. Also, collisions are non-fatal - the hash is an indicator, not taken as the final word.

Comment: @Mitch - I should also mention - there are very few small files to worry about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most cryptographic hashes today, including [MD5](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), [SHA-1](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and the [SHA-2](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family, are based on the [Merkle–Damgård construction](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction).

In this construction, the input is processed by dividing it into fixed-length blocks, which are fed one at a time into a "mixing function" that irreversibly shuffles them together with the internal state of the algorithm (which is also a fixed-length bitstring).  At the end of the input, the resulting internal state is further irreversibly transformed to prevent certain kinds of attacks:

[image: Diagram of the Merkle–Damgård hashing process]

(The upcoming [SHA-3](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) hash standard is based on the newer [cryptographic sponge construction](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function), which differs in some details, but not significantly at the general level discussed here.)

If it weren't for the length padding and finalization steps, you could just take the hash of any message and use it to compute the hash of that message with some extra data appended, just like you can do with CRC.  Alas, this is considered a Bad Thing from a cryptographic viewpoint, and the finalization step is specifically included in the process to make it impossible.

So, if you want to interrupt the hashing process in the middle of the message and resume it later, you need to grab the internal state string *before* it goes through the padding and finalization stages.

(You may also need to store a small amount of additional data, such as the number of blocks processed so far for correct length padding, and, if the hashing is interrupted in the middle of a block, any partial input block not yet fed into the mixing function.)

---

Most crypto libraries implement hash algorithms using a hash object that stores the internal state and allows the input to be supplied in arbitrary pieces, like this (pseudocode):

```c++
HashFunction hash = new SomeHashFunction();
hash.addInput( data );
// ...
hash.addInput( moreData );
BitString output = hash.finalize();
```

Typically, even if the hash objects may not provide direct access to their internal state, they'll usually provide methods for cloning and/or serializing themselves.  I'm not particularly familiar with [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) specifically, but at a glance, it [seems](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_s_h_a256.html) to provide a `Clone()` method.

---

Ps. If you're interested in using cryptographic hashes for file integrity verification, you may want to take a look at [universal hashing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing), and specifically at polynomial-evaluation based universal hash functions like [GHASH](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) or [Poly1305](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305-AES).  These are very fast and parallelizable hash functions that are commonly used as part of [authenticated encryption](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) schemes, but which may also be used on their own as [message authentication codes](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).  The nice thing about them is that not only can they be computed incrementally, but, with some clever mathematics, they can even be incrementally updated if changes are made to the *middle* of the data.  Their main drawback is that, to be cryptographically secure against forgery (e.g. creating two files with the same hash), they need to be used with a secret key.

Answer (score 0):

@Mitch - I know this is an old topic but your request is not out of interest. Now in automotive world there is this new FOTA feature (Firmware Over The Air) where the vehicle firmware (several firmware in several in-car Electronics Control Units) is updated via 4G, WiFi, etc. The firmware is received by the vehicle with possible interruptions (no-network areas, vehicle switched-off...). So we receive the software in several chunks and we need the capability to stop / resume a hash computation (for signature verification purpose). But current automotive crypto SW standard (Autosar) does not provide this feature compared to e.g. PKCS#11 standard.